# MSI Creator's keyboard backlight doesn't work

Tags: fedora, keyboard-backlight

I am a newbie at linux and I have installed Fedora 38 KDE on my laptop. It's turned out that backlight of my built-in keyboard is off although in Windows I can switch it on and off by Fn+F8. Of course I tried pressing Fn+F8).

Also I opened Settings/Shortcuts and tried to assign Fn+F8 to something. And when I pressed the combination nothing happened as if Linux didn't hear this combination at all.

When laptop starts the backlight is on and it switches off when GRUB menu appears.

I tries to use OpenRGB but is says "One or more I2C/SMBus interfaces failed to initialize." Unfortunately, I don't know what I2C is and how it relates to keyboard backlight.

lsusb shows:

```
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 1038:113a SteelSeries ApS SteelSeries KLC
```

**Update**
I found the [information](https://www.reddit.com/r/MSILaptops/comments/u89mx7/comment/j4i0fr0/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) that has helped me to solve the problem.

But I don't understand how it works. I'll appreciate if you explain me)

Comment: https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB/-/issues/2525

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's I got out of the problem. I was inspired by [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/MSILaptops/comments/u89mx7/comment/j4i0fr0/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

First, figure out vendor and product id of your keyboard.

`lsusb` showed me lines and one of them was mine:

`Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1038:113a SteelSeries ApS SteelSeries KLC`

1038 - VendorID, 113a - ProductID

Then get the list of USB devices:

`ls /sys/bus/usb/devices` that shows me quite a few directories like:

`1-0:1.0  3-0:1.0  3-14      3-14:1.1  3-2:1.0  3-8:1.0  3-8:1.2  3-8:1.4  usb1  usb3`

Let's explore each of them in search of idVendor file:

`ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/idVendor`

Okay, some of directories has one. Let's figure out what device corresponds to my VendorId (1038).

`find -L /sys/bus/usb/devices/ -maxdepth 2 -name idVendor -exec sh -c 'echo "{}->"; cat {}' \;`

The part of my output was:

`/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-13/idProduct-> 113a`

If more than one usb device has our vendor we can just check it by productId

`find -L /sys/bus/usb/devices/ -maxdepth 2 -name idProduct -exec sh -c 'echo "{}->"; cat {}' \;`

In my case it was `3-13` usb device.

Let's unbind it.

`echo '3-13' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind`

If back light turns on - congratulations in you!

Now you can save this command in batch file and run on start up.

I saved it to `/opt/fixKB.sh` and added to crontab like this:

`sudo crontab -e`

and entered this line at the end

`@reboot /opt/fixKB.sh`